# Why is the ActionEvent component the wrong type?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have added a few `MultiButton`s dynamically and each has a new `ActionListener`. When the `ActionListener` is called the `Component` is of type `Button` and not the actual `MultiButton` object (i.e. the cast to MultiButton causes a `ClassCastException` cannot cast `Button` to `MultiButton`).

Is there a way to get the `MultiButton` instead? Or have I done something silly?

Code:

```
Container cBob = findContainerBob(f);

cBob.removeAll();

for (String str : things) {
    MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();
    mb.setTextLine1(str);

    mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            MultiButton clickedMb = (MultiButton)evt.getComponent(); // Throws exception                
        });         

    cBob.addComponent(mb);
}
```

Comment: If you cast to the wrong type, you don't get a `null` value - you get a `ClassCastException`. So your description doesn't make sense, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Oh. Yes. I meant that. Question updated. Personal memory error: It was actually a question I began writing on Friday and I remembered the exact symptom wrongly! - still the generic problem is still the same - why is it the wrong type?

Comment: What _exactly_ is `MultiButton`? It's not a standard component

Comment: It is very standard in codenameone: [multibutton](http://www.codenameone.com/using-multibutton.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/MultiButton.java?r=317

If you look at the source of the MultiButton in codenameone, you will see this method:

```
/**
 * Adds an action listener
 * 
 * @param al the action listener
 */
public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
    emblem.addActionListener(al);
}
```

emblem is a member and declared as Button:

```
private Button emblem = new Button();
```

So the Component you get with your `evt.getComponent()` call is indeed a button.

Update:
To get your button as a MultiButton you should use:

```
MultiButton multiButton = (MultiButton) evt.getComponent().getParent().getLeadParent();
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So I can get the multibutton by going to the parent of the component returned and casting *that* to a multibutton...although it would worry me that I can rely on this always working like that!

Comment: Right, I just found this as well and edited my answer.

Comment: Great answer! The reasoning behind this is to make the lead component act like a regular button with compatibility. 
You can use: MultiButton clickedMb = (MultiButton)evt.getComponent().getParent().getLeadParent();

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly, thanks for pointing out the `getLeadParent()`.